# How can I use JFrame.pack() correctly?

Tags: java

Well, Hey guys.
For how I see it, Pack method is used inorder to store in the minimum size that can still hold all the elements inside a frame.(Correct me if I'm worng).

But I think that I'm using it not in the right way.
I tried to add some compoments to a frame under a jpanel.
Then I called the pack method, and the frame suit it self to the compoments.

After I remove all of the old compoments using JFrame.removeAll(), I added new compoments under a new JPanel. And called the pack method again but this time the panel from the begging was in the minimum size that can't hold the first JPanel and not the new JPanel.

My code :

```
public Window() {
    frame = new JFrame("Auto VPN Connection");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addInstace("loading", new JPanel());
    JPanel panel = getInstance("loading");
    panel.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("Loading..");
    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.show();
    Start();
}

public void clearFrame() {
    if (frame.getContentPane().getComponents().length > 0)
        frame.removeAll();
}

public void Start() {
    addInstace("home", new JPanel());
    JPanel panel = getInstance("home");
    panel.setSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
    panel.setLayout(null);
    button.setText("Welcome");
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.revalidate();
}

public JPanel getInstance(String name) {
    for (Pair<String, JPanel>key : array) {
        if (key.getLeft().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return key.getRight();
    }
    return null;
}

public void addInstace(String name, JPanel panel) {
    if (!instanceExists(name)) {
        array.add(new Pair<>(name, panel));
    } else {
        System.out.print("Exists!");
    }
}

public boolean instanceExists(String name) {
    for (Pair<String, JPanel>key : array) {
        if (key.getLeft().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I don't call pack method in Start() so the frame pack It self for the size of the JLabel and It's okay.

But if I do call pack method again in Start(), the frame not pack It self either to the JLabel and to the JButton.

Here are some pictures that exam my situation:

[Pack not called in the Start method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQLdm.png)

[Pack is now called in the Start method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oBJb.png)

Thank you for taking time and read my question, That's it.

Comment: Your usage of pack() is probably fine; the more problematic thing I see is that you give the panel a null layout. You need to use layout managers, they do the work that pack() basically triggers for you.

Comment: @Gimby Hi Gimbly, thanks for the quick answer. Umm, I'll look into what you've mentioned. But can you tell why my current way of doing it is not working?